# Silverlight MVVM and dealing with FOCUS

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm developing complex data entry forms with various pop-up lookups, etc. Because of different things - focus of certain controls get lost and I need some way to set focus in MVVM. So far I came up with attached property which I coded like this(actual dependency property declaration skipped):

```
private static void SetFocus(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = d as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                textBox.Focus();
            }
        }
```

So, it's pretty simple. When property changes - focus get's set.

My view:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentItem.SerialNumber, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                     behaviors:TextBoxBehaviors.IsFocused="{Binding SecondaryControlFocus}"
                     Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TabIndex="2" />
```

As you see - I attach that behavior and Bind to "SecondaryControlFocus" property.

ViewModel:

```
public bool SecondaryControlFocus
        {
            get
            {
                return this.secondaryControlFocus;
            }

            set
            {
                this.secondaryControlFocus = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SecondaryControlFocus);
            }
        }
```

And code how I set focus:

```
this.SecondaryControlFocus = !this.SecondaryControlFocus;
```

To me this code **smells** because I have to toggle property force and back in order to trigger property..

Is there nicer way to accomplish what I do? There is nothing more irritating when power user can't use TAB keys... And I need to get control over focusing in MVVM, this is important for proper data entry flow. But I want code to be somewhat "nice"

Comment: WPF has the ability to setup multiple Focus Scopes, each of which will track Focus individually. Perhaps you can look into that?

Comment: Which control has focus sounds like View logic.  Why are you putting View logic in your ViewModel?  It sounds like you just need to specify your TabIndex or put a small bit of code in an event handler.  Remember, MVVM does not mean no code behind, you can put View logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does smell, but I don't think there's anything we can do about it

Usually I do the same thing you have with the `AttachedProperty`, and keep a single `IsFocused` bool somewhere in the `View` (since this is a View-Specific problem, and should not be mixed in with the business logic). I'll then have the `View` listen to some kind of Event System such as (PRISM's `EventAggregator` or MVVM Light's `Messenger`) for `ResetFocus` events, and I'll raise the `ResetFocus` event whenever something causes focus to change between my windows/pages, or after a dialog box.

It's not pretty, but it works.